# OpenLayers ZoomToExtent doesn´t seem to work properly with WFS layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, wfs

My website has a **list of routes** and a map. When I click on each route it appears its associated information and the **WFS layer** is **selected**. As a base layer I have all the routes obtained with WMS. 
This is a portion of the html code:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript: displayRouteById(245, 417000, 4593700, 426200, 4597475); return false;">
```

What I can´t get is the zoom to each route although the extents are correct. Here is my OpenLayers code:

```
var map, route, extent, routeWMS, draw, modify;

function init() {
    var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(417000,4589000,428000,4592000);
    var resolutions = [1100,550,275,100,50,25,10,5,2,1,0.5,0.25];
    var genericMapOptions = {projection: "EPSG:23031", units: 'm', maxExtent: bounds}

    routeWMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS();

    route = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "Base Vector Layer", 
        {
            isBaseLayer: false,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:23031"),
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: "1.1.0",
                srsName: "EPSG:23031",
                params: {
                    map: "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/mapServer/maps/stcugat/map.map",
                    USERID: userId,
                    PERFILID: profileId
                },
                url: "http://localhost/mapserver/mapserv.exe",
                featureType: "routes",
                featurePrefix: "ms",
                geometryName: "the_geom"
            })
        }
    );

    var layers = [routeWMS, route];

    route.events.register(
        'loadend', 
        route, 
        function() {
            // I get the same extents with the three options
            alert(this.getDataExtent() + "\n" + extent + "\n" + this.features[0].geometry.getBounds());
            //map.zoomToExtent(this.getDataExtent());
            //map.zoomToExtent(extent);
            map.zoomToExtent(this.features[0].geometry.getBounds());
        }
    );

    var mapControls = [ 
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
    ];

    var mapOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
        resolutions: resolutions,
        controls: mapControls
        }, genericMapOptions);

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);
    map.addLayers(layers);

    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}

function displayRouteById(id, minX, minY, maxX, maxY) {
    extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
    route.protocol.params.PERFILID = id;
    route.refresh({force: true});
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is the loadend-event really fired everytime you call the function displayRouteById?

Comment: Yes, I get the alert message with the boundaries... It also works with `route.events.on({"loadend": nameOfFunction});` although in this case the map object gives an unexpected error and even the base layer doesn´t show.

Comment: Finally I have solved it declaring the OpenLayers map boundaries with the same extent as the Mapfile extent coordinates.